# Problems opening the jar

Tags: jar, executable-jar

I made in netbeans a jar, but when I double clicked it, nothing happen

```
C:\Users\itzel\Documents>java -jar ColaDeVuelos.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at GUI.MenuPrincipal.initComponents(MenuPrincipal.java:110)
        at GUI.MenuPrincipal.<init>(MenuPrincipal.java:30)
        at GUI.MenuPrincipal$5.run(MenuPrincipal.java:184)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unkno
```

wn Source)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is running and throwing **NullPointerException**.
I guess there is an error in **MenuPrincipal.java** file.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

at GUI.MenuPrincipal$5.run(MenuPrincipal.java:184)
```

Comment: new MenuPrincipal().setVisible(true); Its this :C, also Im using gifs as setImageIcon

Comment: @rositagalixx I use Java mainly for writing back-end services and data processing. So, I don't have much idea about Swings. Sorry.